# Continuous function on $[0, \infty)$ vanishing at endpoints and with finite values at stationary points - Is it bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

Let $m \geq 1$ be a fixed integer. I have a function $f:[0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}_+$ that is continuous and such that $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{r\to\infty} f(r) = 0$. I also know that its derivative vanishes at two points $r = 0$ and $r=\sqrt{m+1}$, and that $f(\sqrt{m+1})$ is finite.

> Can I conclude that $f$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: You know that a continuous function on a closed interval is bounded, so can you use the end conditions to transform it into a continuous function on a closed interval?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R_+$? The same as $[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 2):

There exists $R$ such that $|f(x)| <1$ for $x >R$. Any continuous fucntion is bounded on $[0,R]$, so there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for $x \leq R$. It follows that $\max \{1,M\}$ is a bound for $|f|$ on $[0,\infty)$.